# PHP: Issue with while loop condition

Tags: php, while-loop

I have the following code, unfortunately it's looping infinity but I can't understand why :

`$tot_age is` set to 604245119

```
while ($tot_age > 536467742) {
        $tot_age - 31536000;
        if  ($tot_age < 536467742 ) {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
```

So what I'm attempting to here is the following. If `$tot_age` is greater than 17 years, iterate through the loop and minus 12 months from $tot_age. I'm then attempting to break out of the loop at the point which $tot_age is less than 17 years. I'll apply some logic here too.

Can anyone see an issue here? Thanks

Comment: You are not setting  `$tot_age - 31536000` here,you are just doing an operation in the air as it were.Change it to `$tot_age=$tot_age - 31536000;`

Comment: Ah, thank you. It's been so long since I've done even basic arithmetic in PHP I appear to have forgotten how.

Comment: @Mihai `$tot_age -= 31536000;` :P

Comment: Sure that works too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
while ($tot_age > 536467742) {
        $tot_age = $tot_age - 31536000;
        if  ($tot_age < 536467742 ) {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd line should read

```
$tot_age = $tot_age - 31536000;
```

Answer (score 4):

Youre not changing the value of tot_age in the loop, you're just making an empty statement. Change:

```
$tot_age - 31536000;
```

to:

```
$tot_age = $tot_age - 31536000;
```